# Ada Language - I've got a single word in my .data segment

Tags: ada, segment

I hope you guys can give me a hand here.

I have an Ada project which compiles correctly. Since I'm a curious person I decided to obj dump my object files. To my surprise, all of my Ada objects have a single word in the .data segment. All have the same name as well, objectname_E. Someone suggested that this is an elaboration flag? Is that correct?

An example.

```
0 .text         00000078  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
1 .data         00000001  00000000  00000000  000000ac  2**0
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  000000ad  2**0
              ALLOC

00000000 g     O .data  00000001 watchdog_driver_E
```

I tried to google this but didn't find anything.

Comment: What compiler are you using? And how are you calling objdump?

Comment: I'm using GNATPRO 6.4.0w-20100323-43, and I'm using the binaries specific to my target (LEON2). To objdump I used leon-elf-objdump.exe

Comment: If you're using GNAT Pro, you presumably have a support contract with AdaCore. They would answer this, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an elaboration flag.

In the main program generated by `gnatbind` you'll find a procedure `adainit` containing for example

```
procedure adainit is
   ...
   E021 : Boolean; pragma Import (Ada, E021, "system__exception_table_E");
   ...
begin
   ...
   System.Exception_Table'Elab_Body;
   E021 := True;
   ...
```

Clearly this might be used within the translated package to tell whether the package has been elaborated and, if not, report access-before-elaboration errors (I say 'might' because I can't immediately see any examples where the elaboration flag is actually accessed).